# Programmatically switch between ad-hoc and regular wireless network

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm using a Raspberry Pi to build a little stand-alone device. On clicking a button, I want to configure an ad-hoc network so a user can connect to the network, use a web-based configuration tool and then the device will join the specified wireless network on exit. I have all the software ready to go, but my knowledge of Linux networking isn't great. I'm using Raspbian Jessie - September 2016.

Here is what I propose to do to start the ad-hoc network.

Change `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 0
    wireless-essid DEVICE
    wireless-mode ad-hoc
```

Although I don't think it should be used at this point, my `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` contains:

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
```

I also have `isc-dhcp-server` running to assign IP addresses when the user connects. The contents of `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` is:

```
ddns-update-style none;
option domain-name "DEVICE";
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

authoritative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.255;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.0.255;
}
```

---

When it's time to change back to the normal network, change `/etc/network/interfaces` to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

I change `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` to:

```
country=GB
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="{{ssid}}"
    psk="{{key}}"
}
```

If I make these changes manually and reboot the device, they work as expected. However, I can't figure out which sequence of commands will cause the new configuration to be applied.

I've tried various combinations of:

`sudo ifdown --force wlan0 && sudo ifup wlan0`,

`sudo service isc-dhcp-server stop`

and

`sudo service networking restart`.

Either I retain the old configuration or the wireless networking is lost until I reboot.

Do my config files look right for both ad-hoc and regular networking? What sequence of commands do I use to switch between them, starting dhcp when in ad-hoc mode and stopping dhcp when in regular mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using configuration instead of interface names, as explained [here](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-reference/ch05.en.html#_the_manually_switchable_network_configuration).

Your *interfaces* file should give descriptions for both cases,

```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

   iface eth0 inet dhcp

   auto wlan0
   allow-hotplug wlan0

   iface adhoc inet static
    address 192.168.0.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    wireless-channel 0
    wireless-essid DEVICE
    wireless-mode ad-hoc

   iface normal inet manual
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

`adhoc` and `normal` are the network configuration names.
 To enable/disable a configuration you should use, *interface=configuration* as argument for *ifupdown*,

```
  # ifup wlan0=adhoc

  # ifdown wlan0=adhoc
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't realise that the interface was different from the 'device'. I'll try this tonight and let you know how I get on. Thanks!